# Merge Two ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, merge, arraylist, .net-2.0

I want to merge all data in two arraylist in c#. Some data in arraylist got same with another arraylist. i don't want duplicate data when merge.

```
ArrayList1   ArrayList2
    1             1
    2             2
    3             4
                  5
```

I've try the coding below. but the result not as i expected:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arrayList2;i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j<arrayList1;j++)
  {
     if(arraylist1[i] == arraylist2[j])
     {
        newArraylist.add(arraylist[i]+"-same");
     }
     else
     {
        newArraylist.add(arraylist[i]+"-from arrayList2");
     }
  }
}
```

The result from code above is :

```
newArrayList
   1 - same
   2 - same
   4 - from arraylist2
   5 - from arraylist2
```

the result that i want :

```
 newArrayList
       1 - same
       2 - same
       3 - from arraylist1
       4 - from arraylist2
       5 - from arraylist2
```

Comment: Given that you're using C# 2, is there any reason you're not using `List<T>`?

Comment: Erm, how can you expect an output of `from arraylist1` when that's not even in your code snippet?

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm using the ArrayList because the old developer leave me this software with ArrayList.. owh why.-_-"

Comment: @Shevek because i don't know how... please help.

Comment: Get generic, abandon arraylist.

Comment: @Jodrell for the some reason, i can't change the arrayList. because it will effect the whole software.

Comment: @QusyaireEzwan, Is the list Always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var arrayList1 = new ArrayList {1, 2, 3};
var arrayList2 = new ArrayList {1, 2, 4, 5};
var newList = new ArrayList();

foreach (var item in arrayList1)
{
    if(arrayList2.Contains(item))
    {
        newList.Add(string.Format("{0} - same", item));
        arrayList2.Remove(item);
    }
    else
    {
        newList.Add(string.Format("{0} - from arrayList1", item));
    }
}

foreach(var item in arrayList2)
{
    newList.Add(string.Format("{0} - from arrayList2", item));
}
```

This will give you this result:

```
1 - same
2 - same
3 - from arraylist1
4 - from arraylist2
5 - from arraylist2
```

Answer (score 4):

The most simple and easiest way is using LINQ

```
var collection1 = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 3 };
var collection2 = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
var mergedList = new ArrayList();
mergedList.AddRange(collection1);
mergedList.AddRange(collection2.ToArray().Where(item => !collection1.ToArray().Contains(item)).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", mergedList.ToArray()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: collection1 doesn't need to be converted to an array to check Contains(item).

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the items and seee it it is contained in the first array.

```
foreach (int item in arrayList2)
{
    if (!arrayList1.Contains(item))
        arrayList1.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing based on index, which won't work. `ArrayList1[2]` contains `3`, while `ArrayList1[2]` contains `4`.

You'll have to use `.Contains()` to check whether the number is present in the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
var collection1 = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 3 };
var collection2 = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

var merge = collection1.ToArray().Union(collection2.ToArray()).Distinct();
var result = new List<String>();
foreach (var val in merge)
{
    var newString = string.Empty;
    if (collection1.Contains(val) && collection2.Contains(val))
        newString = val.ToString() + " - same";
    else if (collection1.Contains(val))
        newString = val.ToString() + " - from list 1";
    else
         newString = val.ToString() + " - from list 2";
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
    result.Add(newString);
}
```

Produces output

```
1 - same
2 - same
3 - from list 1
4 - from list 2
5 - from list 2
```

Comment: Union is a 3.5 feature. Not available in 2.0

Comment: My bad. Well, own Union() method can be written easily enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option would be using Union (LINQ).
To find out how it works check this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/union